# Infinite request after login

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a site where I want to login programmatically in a scenario sending credentials to API(endpoint). So the app is working well if I log in manually.

Now I have a condition, if it's true, just do a login, this code is in app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

{
    this.initializeApp();
}

initializeApp() {

    if((this.platform.is('mobileweb') || this.platform.is('desktop')) && this.id == "C3E1EE21-A62C-452F-BE0D-AC3EF5449F23"){
    
              //Authenticate 
              var loginModel: myLoginModel =  
              {
                applicationId: "C1F3A7D7-709D-EB11-A008-00155E00F00B",
                username: "username",
                password: "pwrd5893"
              };
    
              this._auth.login(loginModel).then(token => {
                let user:any = jwt_decode(token);
                user.token = token;
                this.storageService.setItem('user',user);
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });

      this.navController.navigateRoot('myScreen');

    }
}
}
```

the _auth.login method is on auth.service.ts:

```
login(credentials): Promise<any> {
    return this._api.security_post('Login', credentials)
    .then((res: any) => {
      this.storageService.setItem('token',res);
      return res;
    }).catch(e => {
      this.logout();
      return e;
    })
  }
```

And this._api.security_post used on auth.login it's on api.service.ts

```
security_post(url, data) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':  'application/json' }),
        responseType: 'text' as 'json'
      };
      this.http.post(this.apiSecurity+'/'+url, data, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data)
      },error=>{
        reject(error);
      });
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

So the app login correctly, but it keeps doing infinite login request

[image]

How can I solve that? Regards

Comment: just assign the new route, so it change /login to /myscreen @ABOS

Comment: Yes, it is called after login success, it's working, it redirects to /myscreen correctly and start with infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the condition under which you want to login programmatically is `this.id == "C3E1EE21-..."`?

In that case, I suppose it remains `true` throughout your App session, and therefore the block is executed at each component update.

A possible solution could be to add an extra condition, typically to login only if you currently have no known user in your session:

```
if((
  this.platform.is('mobileweb')
  || this.platform.is('desktop')
) && this.id == "C3E1EE21-..."
&& !this.storageService.getItem('user') ) {
          //Authenticate...
}
```